# Call a HTML File From Jar

Tags: java, html, file, jar

Im generating a report from a template html file in my program. It resides in /src/main/resources and its name is "template.html". Im using ClassLoader inside the code like this:

```
   private String readTemplateFile() {
        String str = "";
        URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("template.html");

        try {
            FileReader input = new FileReader(url.getFile());
            BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(input);
            String line;

            line = bufRead.readLine();
            str = line;
            while (line != null) {
                line = bufRead.readLine();
                str += line + "\n";

            }
            bufRead.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        return str;
    }
```

It is doing nicely when you run the code inside IDE but when i make a runnable jar from it, it is generating an empty report. What is the solution? Thanks for reading.

Comment: `e.printStackTrace();` try this and tell us the error message while running from jar

Comment: Sorry i couldnt get the log in text so i got print screen of it:http://img51.imageshack.us/img51/7410/captureueu.jpg   i browsed the jar with 7zip and there is a "template.html" in the root directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's in a jar, it's no longer a file.

Use [ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to retrieve the resource as an `InputStream`.

Then [convert the InputStream to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/in-java-how-do-a-read-convert-an-inputstream-in-to-a-string).

Comment: Thanks a billion! It worked flawlessly! I cant thank you enough :)